# Use a service injected by dependency injection in a static constant of the same component

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I use Angular and now I want to use the service, that is injected by dependency injection, as value for a static variable.

Let me show:

This is the constructor where the Helper Service is injected

```
  constructor(private _helperService: HelperService) {

  }
```

Now I want to use this Service here:

```
public static readonly setDataFunction = ProductsComponent._helperService.setData;
```

There I get the error message: Property '_helperService' does not exist on type 'typeof ProductsComponent'

I haven't done that before so I don't know how I can use this _helperService in a static constant.

I've already searched for solutions but haven't found anything that has helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The _helperService that you have injected in constructor is instance variable and it is accessible only inside HelperService class this object.

Define a _helperService as a static variable in ProductsComponent

```
static _helperService: any;
```

In constructor initialize the _helperService with HelperService using injector

```
import { Injector } from "@angular/core";  

constructor(injector: Injector){
    ProductsComponent._helperService = injector.get(HelperService);
}
```